# Qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer um CRUD para um framework da maneira mais genérica possível?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-pattern, ado.net

Estou estudando para fazer um CRUD para um framework mas estou tento alguns problemas para poder fazer isso da maneira mais genérica possível.

Por exemplo:

tenho uma classe `Pessoa()` 
Quero fazer o CRUD passando somente o objeto Pessoa para uma outra classe em uma outra camada como por exemplo: `DAL.AccessData(Pessoa objPessoa)`.
E dentro dessa classe `DAL.AccessData(Pessoa objPessoa)` eu teria os meus métodos: `insert/delete/update/select`.

Como seria a melhor maneira de se fazer isso? Claro, usando também o conceito de injeção de dependência com inversão de controle?

Comment: Você já pensou em usar o entity framework?

Comment: Então.. Eu pensei em utilizar o entity somente pra criar as minhas models. Eu queria fazer na mão pra aprender, imagino que assim será mais fácil de fixar os conceitos na mente. As vezes agente acaba usando um framework como o entities e não sabe exatamente o que acontece por dentro. ;) @Makah

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português, uma sugestão é você colocar a linguagem da qual busca informação no título da pergunta, isso ajuda na busca pela resposta.

Comment: @LuizCarvalho obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @LuizCarvalho da onde você inventou isso? Ninguém faz isso no SO.

Comment: @Makah de onde eu inventei? é óbvio que fazem... além da tag a informação da linguagem/tecnologia utilizada na pergunta ajuda e muito outros usuários com a mesma dúvida e obviamente a identificação de alguém que possa respondê-la.

Comment: Um outro ORM (object-relational mapper) que é bastante simples e opensource é [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). Já usei com bastante sucesso.

Comment: É @LuizCarvalho, realmente estamos precisando de uma moderação e uma pessoa que saiba das regras do SO para conseguirmos colocar referências de boas práticas.

Comment: @LuizCarvalho Isso foi (pouco) discutido no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-titulo/298#298). Dê sua opinião lá.

Comment: @Makah Isso foi (pouco) discutido no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-titulo/298#298). Dê sua opinião lá.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O que você quer, pelo que eu entendi, é implementar seu próprio Framework com as operações CRUD. Acho que nesta primeira etapa não é necessário usar inversão de controle de injeção de dependência.

Primeiro pense como vai ser a arquitetura de dados. Você pode usar classes de negócio, como **Repositórios**, por exemplo, ou então implementar a camada de acesso a dados (DAL) diretamente. O ideal é que essa camada de acesso a dados seja embasada em uma interface usando um tipo genérico. Vou dar um exemplo pra ficar mais claro:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAcessoDados<T>
        where T: class
    {
        List<T> Selecionar();
        List<T> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores); 
        void Incluir(T objeto);
        void Atualizar(T objeto);
    }
}
```

Toda e qualquer classe de acesso a dados deve usar essa interface. Isso garante que os métodos são os mesmos para todas as classes de dados.

Repare que `Selecionar` é polimórfico. Chamando sem operadores, você deve implementar um método que irá selecionar todos os elementos da sua fonte de dados (um banco de dados relacional, por exemplo). No segundo você deve implementar um método que selecione os dados de acordo com alguns parâmetros.

Você também pode implementar uma classe comum que implementa essa interface, mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Data
{
    public abstract class Comum<T>: IDisposable, IComum<T>
        where T: class
    {
        #region Propriedades

        protected string ConexaoBancoDados { get; set; }

        private String _whereOuAnd = " WHERE ";
        protected String WhereOuAnd
        {
            get
            {
                var retorno = _whereOuAnd;
                _whereOuAnd = " AND ";
                return retorno;
            }
        }

        private string _virgulaOuEspaco = " ";
        public String VirgulaOuEspaco {
            get
            {
                var retorno = _virgulaOuEspaco;
                _virgulaOuEspaco = ", ";
                return retorno;
            }
        }

        protected void ReiniciarWhereEVirgula()
        {
            _whereOuAnd = " WHERE ";
            _virgulaOuEspaco = " ";
        }

        #endregion

        #region Construtores

        protected Comum() { }

        protected Comum(String conexaoBancoDados)
        {
            ConexaoBancoDados = conexaoBancoDados;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Métodos

        /// <summary>
        /// Overload que retorna uma lista com todos os objetos do tipo T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// Lista com objetos do tipo Job.
        /// </returns>
        public virtual List<T> Selecionar()
        {
            return Selecionar(new List<Operador>());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Método selecionar padrão. Recebe uma lista de operadores para selecionar do banco e devolver uma lista
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operadores"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks>Deve ser implementado em cada classe derivada.</remarks>
        public abstract List<T> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores);

        public abstract void Incluir(T objeto);
        public abstract void Atualizar(T objeto);

        #endregion

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Se suas classes de dados herdarem desta classe `Comum`, automaticamente o C# obriga você a implementar o método `Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores)` (por ser abstract) e sua classe de acesso a dados já ganha um método chamado `Selecionar()` sem parâmetros. Aí você pode implementar sua classe como essa de um projeto meu:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Data
{
    public class AtividadesComentarios : Comum<AtividadesComentario>, IDisposable
    {
        public AtividadesComentarios() { }
        public AtividadesComentarios(String conexaoBancoDados) : base(conexaoBancoDados) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parametros"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override List<AtividadesComentario> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operadores.Operador> operadores)
        {
            using (var obj = new Common.Database())
            {
                var sSql =
                    "select ac.ID_COMENTARIO, ac.ID_ATIVIDADE, ac.TEXTO, ac.DATA, ac.ID_USUARIO, ac.HISTORICO_ANTIGO " +
                    " from ATIVIDADES_COMENTARIOS ac ";

                foreach (var operador in operadores)
                {
                    sSql += WhereOuAnd + " ac." + operador;
                }

                var parametros = operadores.Where(o => o.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Igual))).Select(o2 => ((Igual)o2).ParametroOracle).ToList();
                var retorno = new List<AtividadesComentario>();
                OracleConnection connection;

                using (OracleDataReader reader = obj.ConsultarSqlReader(ConexaoBancoDados, sSql, parametros, out connection))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        retorno.Add(new AtividadesComentario
                        {
                            AtividadesComentarioId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID_COMENTARIO")),
                            AtividadeId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID_ATIVIDADE")),
                            UsuarioId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID_USUARIO")),
                            HistoricoAntigoId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("HISTORICO_ANTIGO")),
                            Texto = reader.GetOracleClob(reader.GetOrdinal("TEXTO")).Value,
                            Data = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("DATA"))
                        });
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }

                return retorno;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inclui um novo comentário na atividade.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objeto">O objeto a ser inserido.</param>
        public override void Incluir(AtividadesComentario objeto)
        {
            try
            {
                var oDataBase = new Database();
                objeto.AtividadesComentarioId = oDataBase.RecuperaIDSequence(ConexaoBancoDados, "SEQ_ID_COMENTARIO_ATIVIDADE");
                const string sSql = "INSERT INTO ATIVIDADES_COMENTARIOS (ID_COMENTARIO, ID_ATIVIDADE, TEXTO, DATA, ID_USUARIO, HISTORICO_ANTIGO) " +
                                    " VALUES (:ID_COMENTARIO, :ID_ATIVIDADE, :TEXTO, :DATA, :ID_USUARIO, :HISTORICO_ANTIGO)";

                var oParams = ExtrairParametros(objeto);
                oDataBase.ExecutaComandoNonQuery(ConexaoBancoDados, sSql, oParams.ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }


        public override void Atualizar(AtividadesComentario objeto)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Aquele objeto `oDatabase` é um objeto que comunica com a tecnologia específica do seu banco de dados (no meu caso, um banco Oracle). Repare que eu ainda não deixei muito genérico, mas se você for melhorando esse padrão (por exemplo, fazendo o método `Inserir` da classe `Comum` ler as propriedades de um objeto de dados e montar um SQL dinâmico), acredito que você possa chegar num resultado bem legal sem usar muito código específico.

Vou dar mais algumas dicas de métodos que construí pra ler objetos de dados via Reflection:

**Extrair Chaves Primárias de um Objeto de Dados**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extrai a chave primária de um objeto (property decorada com o atributo [Key]).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objeto">Um objeto pertencente ao Namespace Metadata.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected IEnumerable<OracleParameter> ExtrairChavesPrimarias(Object objeto)
    {
        var type = objeto.GetType();
        var properties =
            type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var keyAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof (KeyAttribute)) as KeyAttribute;
            if (keyAttribute != null)
            {
                var columnAttribute = (ColumnAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

                if (columnAttribute != null)
                {
                    yield return new OracleParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                        Value = property.GetValue(objeto, null)
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new OracleParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = property.Name,
                        Value = property.GetValue(objeto, null)
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Extrair Parâmetros de um Objeto de Dados**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Método selecionar padrão. Recebe uma lista de operadores para selecionar do banco e devolver uma lista
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operadores"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks>Deve ser implementado em cada classe derivada.</remarks>
    public abstract List<T> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores);

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(Object objeto)
    {
        return objeto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Monta uma lista de parâmetros por Reflection. Um parâmetro é uma property decorada com o atributo [Column].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objeto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected IEnumerable<OracleParameter> ExtrairParametros(Object objeto)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(objeto))
        {
            var columnAttribute = (ColumnAttribute)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (columnAttribute != null)
            {
                yield return new OracleParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                    Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(objeto, null)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new OracleParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = propertyInfo.Name,
                    Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(objeto, null)
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Se precisar que eu detalhe a resposta em mais algum ponto, só falar.

Answer (score 6):

Porque não dá uma olhada no PetaPoco (http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)?

Ele é baseado no framework utilizado aqui no StackOverflow e possui métodos do tipo Insert(object) que insere o objeto diretamente na base. E a velocidade é infinitamente maior do que Entity Framework ou Linq to SQL =)

Alguns exemplos do site:

```
// Represents a record in the "articles" table
public class article
{
    public long article_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public bool draft { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

// Create a PetaPoco database object
var db=new PetaPoco.Database("connectionStringName");

// Show all articles    
foreach (var a in db.Query<article>("SELECT * FROM articles"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", a.article_id, a.title);
}

// Create the article
var a=new article();
a.title="My new article";
a.content="PetaPoco was here";
a.date_created=DateTime.UtcNow;

// Insert it
db.Insert("articles", "article_id", a);

// by now a.article_id will have the id of the new article
```

Comment: Poxa... =) vou dar uma olhada! Não conhecia esse framework. Mas assim como disse no comentário à cima eu queria fazer um desde o início pra aprender como as coisas funcionam por trás das cortinas se é que me entende! ;)

Comment: Entendo. E como o Dapper (o framework utilizado pelo StackOverflow) e o PetaPoco são open source, há muito o que aprender com eles (especialmente a parte de mapping).

Answer (score 3):

Vale ressaltar que existe uma diferença de nível de abstração entre padrões como MVC, MVP, MVVM e aqueles padrões Enterprise ou da GoF (Adapter, Iterator, Bridge, Composite, Intercepting Filter, etc).

Os primeiros são padrões **arquiteturais**, estão um nível acima na hierarquia de abstração.

---

Há um tempo topei com este [artigo](http://cirw.in/blog/time-to-move-on).

Como é algo novo, não existe literatura sobre isso (e eu bem que procurei, pois pretendia fazer meu TCC sobre isso, mas não encontrei quase nada aproveitável).

## Qual o "problema" com o MVC?

O padrão arquitetural concebido por Trygve Reenskaug, foi pensado para aplicações desktop. Como é algo altamente abstraído, foi possível adaptá-lo e modá-lo ao longo do tempo até chegar nas várias implementações que vemos hoje. E funciona bem! Só é meio confuso.

No artigo que coloquei acima, ele destaca que a confusão maior se dá na definição de `Controller`. É difícil delimitar qual a função dessa camada.

**Exemplo:**

Numa aplicação desktop, o controller é aquela parte que fica ouvindo eventos e chamando callbacks para os mesmos (será que é só isso?).

Numa aplicação web tradicional, boa parte da função do controller é realizada pelo próprio navegador, você nem precisa se preocupar com isso. O papel dele é então apenas interpretar os parâmetros da requisição afim de selecionar qual a fonte de dados para buscar os dados e qual será a `View` utilizada para exibir esses dados.

E quando a aplicação é "dinâmica", no sentido de que existem várias interações que são mediadas pelo Javascript? Toda vez que você faz

```
document.querySelector('#some-element').addEventListener('click', function(){...});
```

e suas variações, você está implementando um controller, muito mais parecido com o de aplicações desktop.

Essa flexibilidade na definição é boa, mas também atrapalha, deixa muito desenvolvedor por aí perdido.

## A proposta do MOVE

Pra retirar a nebulosidade em torno dos controllers, a ideia é criar dois conjuntos bem delimitados que representam as ações do usuário:

- **Operations:** o que se quer fazer? Cadastrar um post, fazer login, listar dados...
- **Events:** o ato de requisitar uma operação, ou seja, uma tentativa de realizar login, o envio de dados para cadastro, etc.

O Symfony Framework já possui um [componente](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) de eventos server-side, o que ajudaria a criar aplicações com esse novo estilo arquitetural, mas eu nunca vi nada implementado.

Talvez seja um pouco cedo para tentar utilizar MOVE em aplicações reais, mas é uma ideia interessante.