# Entity Framework com bancos Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Estou criando uma aplicação no qual irá utilizar um banco de dados o Oracle, porém ao inserir o **.edmx** (Entity Data Model) me deparei com a seguinte situação!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não consigo criar uma conexão com o Banco Oracle. O que eu preciso fazer pra que isso seja feito? Tenho que instalar algum driver? Ou não é possível trabalhar com entity framework e bancos Oracle?

Comment: É necessário instalar um *driver* para o banco de dados Oracle, assim o Visual Studio reconhece o driver e mostra a opção nesse *wizard*. Já passei por esse problema utilizando o PostgreSQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, o ODP.NET:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Aqui tem mais algumas informações:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Até o momento desta resposta, o Entity Framework não trabalha bem com Oracle, mas você pode escrever seu próprio `Repository` com as operações de banco e fazer um `override` do seu contexto para se comportar como um Entity Framework nativo.

Tenho um projeto que trabalha assim. Se quiser seguir por este caminho, por favor, faça mais perguntas que vou postando exemplos de código que você possa trabalhar.

---

**EDIT**

Eu tinha dito que Oracle não trabalha com Entity Framework, mas esta resposta ficou desatualizada, então estou atualizando.

Primeiro é preciso instalar o pacote NuGet [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/). A configuração do `Web.config` deve ficar assim:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

É preciso definir também uma *connection string* para o Oracle para funcionar corretamente.

Feito isso, basta trabalhar normalmente com o Entity Framework que deve funcionar.

Comment: Cigano, sei que o tópico é meio antigo mas tenho interesse em saber como você fez esse repository, pode me enviar alguma coisa pra eu dar uma olhada? Ou o Entity já suporta bem o Oracle? Obrigado.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida O EF já suporta bem o Oracle, mas na época [fiz algo assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/qual-seria-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-fazer-um-crud-para-um-framework-da-maneira-mai/5658#5658). Isto é válido se você usar ADO.NET ou Dapper, e não EF.

Comment: Maravilha, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui estão [todos os Ado .Net Data providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) para os diversos bancos de dados. Alguns desses Drivers não funcionam corretamente, mas os pagos sim funcionam. Então só para ratificar que dependendo o banco e dependendo a versão do banco não acompanham o desenvolvimento e melhoramento do ORM Entity Framework.