# Criar padrão de cadastro com repositório C# UI

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, winforms

criei no meu sistema um repositório com EF6, cada cadastro que faço eu acesso os métodos do meu repositório para comitar as ações que eu preciso (Insert, Delete etc...).
O problema é que meu sistema está bem grande e eu preciso ganhar agilidade ao criar cadastros, pensei então em criar um controle com o padrão de tela que eu preciso e nos botões que vão chamar meu repositório para executar as ações eu penso em criar propriedades informado qual é a tabela do meu Model. Alguém tem algum norte para eu criar algo parecido?

Comment: use DI assim você passa a interface

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria algo usando *Generics*:

```
public interface IComum<T>
    where T: class, IModeloDeDados
{
    IEnumerable<T> Selecionar();
    IEnumerable<T> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> parametros, IEnumerable<string> campos = null);
    void Incluir(T objeto);
    void Atualizar(T objeto);
}
```

Esmiucei melhor a questão [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/qual-seria-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-fazer-um-crud-para-um-framework-da-maneira-mai/5658#5658).

Só esclarecendo, neste meu exemplo um `Operador` é uma classe especial que é transformada em sentença SQL porque o projeto não usa Entity Framework, mas [há outras respostas aqui com a implementação suportando expressões lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16122/como-implementar-o-padr%C3%A3o-repository-no-c-com-ef).

Faça suas classes de repositório implementarem essa interface, passando como tipo em `T` o objeto de dados desejado:

```
public class Pessoas : Comum<Pessoa> { }
```

`Pessoa`, neste caso, precisa implementar uma interface `IModeloDeDados`, para que o repositório não aceite qualquer objeto.