# Método Genérico de Localizar, utilizando ADO.NET e Procedures

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, ado.net, interface, genéricos

Estou procurando uma solução de um repositório genérico para um DAL com um método de Localizar genérico, para não ter redundância no meu código. Utilizando ADO.NET e Procedures.

Achei algo nesse link:

[Qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer um CRUD para um framework da maneira mais genérica possível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/qual-seria-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-fazer-um-crud-para-um-framework-da-maneira-mai)

Assinatura genérica:

```
List Selecionar(IEnumerable operadores);
```

Mas não entendi muito bem como trabalhar com essa lista de operadores.

Uma vez que irei utilizar Procedure passando os parâmetros para minha Procedure, existe alguma maneira prática de eu passar os operadores para minha Procedure de maneira genérica utilizando o ADO.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, na verdade funcionaria de maneira análoga.

Suponha o método `List Selecionar(IEnumerable operadores)`, solicitado como exemplo:

```
public override List<MeuObjeto> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operadores.Operador> operadores)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spMinhaSpDeSelecao", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (var operador in operadores)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + operador.Nome, operador.Valor);
        }

        SqlParameter valorSaida = new SqlParameter();
        valorSaida.ParameterName = "@ValorSaida";
        valorSaida.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        valorSaida.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(valorSaida);

        con.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return new MeuObjeto 
            {
                Campo1 = reader["Campo1"].ToString(),
                Campo2 = reader["Campo2"].ToString(),
                Campo3 = reader["Campo3"].ToString(),
                ...
            };
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal cara, me deu uma visão boa o seu código valeu mesmo. Mas uma coisa, antes de passar a Lista operadores para o método você popularia essa Lista com parâmetros como ? Pq o método recebe uma lista do tipo fixo Operador já com os parâmetros setados nessa lista.

Comment: @FranciscoProença Veja na outra resposta o método `ExtrairParametros`. Acho que vai ajudar.